# How can I see all the revisions where a given line of a file has been modified?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, ankhsvn

I am working with [AnkhSVN](http://ankhsvn.open.collab.net/) in Visual Studio 2008 , and I am trying to figure out a way to **see all the revisions where a specific line of a given file has been modified** (created/changed), so that I can trace when a given bug has been introduced.

I am pretty sure this is possible with some scripting magic with SVN in command-line (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3376892/how-to-find-out-which-revision-contained-a-certain-line-in-svn)), but is there a way to **do that with AnkhSVN or TortoiseSVN** in a Windows environment ?

Comment: Do you mean `blame`, or actually viewing all of the commits for each line? (As if you were to do a `blame`, then recursively go to the revision just before that one and do another `blame` from there, and keep going until the line disappears?) I don't know how to do the latter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the closest you can get using those tools is by using the *Blame* command.

Unfortunately, blame will show you the *last* revision a specific line has been modified only.

Comment: Wow ! I didn't even know this existed ! This is more than enough in my case ! In the version I use, AnkhSVN 2.1.8420.8 , this feature is called "Annotate", though.

Comment: Little tip, you can right-click the revision headers in the left column, and click 'Annotate' again. If you lower the high revision by 1 here, you get the version before the current revision of that line.