# svn version reversion

Tags: svn, version

I accidentally svn upped into a wrong version which broke things. I don't know the version number of the last working build. I want to revert to the last working build, how to do it?

Thanks,

Comment: Just keep upping until you get a build that works... how would SVN know which revision was the last one to work properly?

Answer (score 1):

svn itself does not remember what revision you had checked out before your last "svn up". So there's no easy "undo" for a bad update.

If you know *when* you last updated to a working version, and you didn't explicitly specify a revision number at the time, then you can pass that time to "svn up" to go back to "HEAD at the time".

Alternatively, you can try to move backward through the history of revisions, testing each one until you find a "good" one. The command `svn up -rPREV` will move you back by one change.

If you know that the update brought in a large number of new revisions, so that stepping back one by one would take a long time, then a binary search as [described in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3376892/how-to-find-out-which-revision-contained-a-certain-line-in-svn/3385779#3385779) can help.